# Windows App gets automatically log-out in Surface and Slate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, componentart

I am creating windows 8 app for chart dashboard, I am using ComponentArt tool for creating the chart.
The rendering time for chart is about 1 to 2 minutes because of bit large data.

While rendering the chart, when we tap on screen for multiple times, the App get automatically logout.

I have checked in both windows surface and Samsung slate, It produces the same defect.
This problem is not occurred on checking in desktop.
can anyone tell what the problem is.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by compressing the incoming data using GZip Compression. Because of compressing the data, the file size get reduced and the loading time is decreased to half of it. So it avoids the logout issue as well.